# why doesn't lit() function work in selectExpr()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df.selectExpr(func.lit(20)).show()
df.selectExpr("func.lit(20)").show()
```

Throwing Error :

```
raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
TypeError: Column is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use

```
df.select(func.lit(20))
```

or

```
df.selectExpr("20")
```

`selectExpr` expects a raw SQL string that can be selected, while `select` expects a `column` object, such as `func.lit(20)`, or a column name as a string.

`column`s should not be used in `selectExpr`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how does the selectExpr() works fine with count(colname) ? Eg: df.selectExpr("count(age)").show()

Comment: @JPS because `count` is a valid SQL function that can be used in an SQL query string.